# how to implement follow map with cytoscape.js?

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js

How to use cytoscape.js to achieve the following figure?

1. The midpoint of the edge can be moved.
2. The color of the lines on both sides of the midpoint can be different.

   [image: Img]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mid arrows, but a single edge isn't going to be drawn as two edges.  Refer to the stylesheet docs: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style